# Read in a template file, populate using user input and and generate a new file

Tags: perl

I am trying to read in a template config file (template.config) that looks like this:

```
;;path to speedseq package binary directory
$;SPEEDSEQ_BIN_DIR$; = /usr/local/packages/
;;Sequence file 1
$;Seq1File$; =
;;Sequence file 2
$;Seq2File$; =
;;Read Group
$;Read_Group$;='@RG\tID:NA12878\tSM:NA12878\tPL:ILLUMINA\tLB:NA12878\tPU:NA12878'
;;Reference
$;Reference$; =

;;Output Chromosome
$;Chromosome$; = 
;;use --v for verbose summary
$;OTHER_ARGS$; = --v
```

whose fields will get populated by user input on the command line, e.g.:

```
perl script.pl template.config USER_INPUT.txt USER_INPT2.txt USER_INPUT_REF.txt USER_INPUT_CHR.txt
```

and it will output a new populated config file like this:

```
;;path to speedseq package binary directory
$;SPEEDSEQ_BIN_DIR$; = /usr/local/packages/
;;Sequence file 1
$;Seq1File$; = "USER_INPUT.txt"
;;Sequence file 2
$;Seq2File$; = "USER_INPT2.txt"
;;Read Group
$;Read_Group$;='@RG\tID:NA12878\tSM:NA12878\tPL:ILLUMINA\tLB:NA12878\tPU:NA12878'
;;Reference
$;Reference$; = "USER_INPUT_REF.txt"

 ;;Output Chromosome
 $;Chromosome$; = "USER_INPUT_CHR.txt"
 ;;use --v for verbose summary
 $;OTHER_ARGS$; = --v
I am not sure how to read
```

in the template and mark the fields I need to fill up in an array. How can I do this?

So far I am just reading the config file in my script :

```
open($fpCFG, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Error! Cannot open $sConfigFile for reading: $!";

    $sComponent = $sParam = $sValue = $sDesc = "";
    while (<$fpCFG>) {
        $_ =~ s/\s+$//;
        next if ($_ =~ /^#/);
        next if ($_ =~ /^$/);

        if ($_ =~ m/^\[(\S+)\]$/) {
            $sComponent = $1;
            next;
        }
        elsif ($_ =~ m/^;;\s*(.*)/) {
            $sDesc .= "$1.";
            next;
        }
        elsif ($_ =~ m/\$;(\S+)\$;\s*=\s*(.*)/) {
            $sParam = $1;
            $sValue = $2;

            if ((defined $sValue) && ($sValue !~ m/^\s*$/)) {
                $phConfig->{$sComponent}{$sParam} = ["$sValue", "$sDesc"];
            }

            $sParam = $sValue = $sDesc = "";
            next;
        }
    }

    close($fpCFG);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer responds more directly to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662110/use-user-input-to-populate-a-template-config-file-having-different-subsections-w).  That is marked as "duplicate" of this one, while the existing answer here cannot handle that question, thus this answer. For the requirements and input file format please see the link.  In short: There are multiple sections (like the one here) and order of lines within the section need be kept, as well as the order of sections.

There are a few components to this.

1. User input has to be organized somehow. We can provide a set of named options, and a translation of option names to corresponding lines in the input file. This is done using a particular [Getopt option](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash), along with a translation hash. (It can be organized in yet another way.)
2. A pair of lines identify where to apply user input, and their order need be maintained.  For this we can use an array-ref for lines, being a value for the section-name key for the hash. The array keeps the order.  The hash is not necessary (it can all be in one big array) but provides flexibility for future. The order of sections in the hash is maintained in a separate array. (Or one can add that to the hash.)

All supported options must be explicitly listed in the file. Here we define two.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use feature qw(say);

# Translate user input <--> description line (;;) in file
my ($o1, $o2) = qw(o1 o2);
my %desc = (
    $o1 => 'Sequence file 1', 
    $o2 => 'Output Chromosome',
    # ...
);
my %input;
GetOptions(\%input, "$o1=s", "$o2=s");

my $config_file = 'config.txt';
open my $in_fh, '<', $config_file;

my (%conf, @mod_order, $mod_name, $des, $enter_input);
while (my $line = <$in_fh>)
{
    chomp($line);
    next if $line =~ m/^\s*$/;
    # Name of new section ([]), for hash and order-array
    if ($line =~ m/^\[(.*)\]$/) {
        push @mod_order, $mod_name = $1;
    }

    # A description (;;) line
    if ( ($des) = $line =~ m/^;;(.*)/ ) {
        # Check for input and remember it for next iteration
        for (keys %desc) {
            if (exists $input{$_} and $des =~ /^$desc{$_}/) {
                $enter_input = process_input($desc{$_}, $input{$_});
                last;
            }
        }
        # Keep the description line, it need be printed too
        push @{$conf{$mod_name}}, $line . "\n";
        next;
    }

    if ($enter_input) {
        # Overwrite what is there or append
        $line =~ s/(.*?=)(.*)/$1 $enter_input/;
        $enter_input = '';
    }

    push @{$conf{$mod_name}}, $line . "\n";
}
close $in_fh;

say @{$conf{$_}} for @mod_order;

# In case user's raw input need be processed further
sub process_input {
    my ($desc, $raw_input) = @_;
    # Example (comment): prepend path for `Chromosome` input
    # if ($desc =~ /Ouput Chromosome/) {
    #     return '/data/usr/' . $raw_input;
    # else {
    return $raw_input;
    # }
}
```

The program can be invoked with at most the two provided options, or either, or none.

```
script.pl -o1 INPUT_FOR_FILE_SEQ_1 -o2 INPUT_FOR_CHROMO
```

Curtesy of `Getopt::Long` all manner of malformed input is detected.  The input file is hard-coded but it can be another command-line option or read in via `< config.txt`.  Instead of printing to screen the file can be overwritten in the program, or the print redirected.

Comment: I just have one additional question, it may make this more complicated but for few options for eg ";;Output Chromosome" can I add some hardcoded string to the user input before writing it in output file - for eg user input is` -o2 INPUT_FOR_CHROMO` but my output file get value  - `/data/usr/INPUT_FOR_CHROMO`? I would need to edit/check this in the if condition for $des and $lines values right? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot @zdim! This keeps the code so much cleaner, I was trying to use condition inside the if loop. Just one more question- this user input process work only for one field like "$;Chromosome$;" or will in envoke for every input? in later case should I specify some condition insdie if loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot zdim! Yes I am working on the line of modifying the subroutine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zdim! I have one more question :) What if I want to update a field in just just module, but that field happens to occur in modules too ( ie it is not unique but I know exactly which module it should populate). I would make another subroutine to check for module name as well right?

Comment: @AnkP  You have the `$mod_name` set  in the previous iteration (and remembered). So just it to the `process_input` sub and condition processing on whether it matches the name of the module you want.  At this point you start hitting the design limitations -- you are developing a templating system, and the intricacies will start coming in.

Comment: Thanks @zdim! Yes this is the last piece in this code to make it as flexible. Thanks for your guidance. The script covers all possible combinations now!

Comment: Hi @Zdim, I know my problem has been resolved, but i had a doubt regarding the Getopt method of input you used. Can I assign/hardcode some values for variables like $o1 or $o2..etc and add them the %input hash rather than using Getopt long for taking all inputs? Would creating an input like `%input = ($o1, $o2, $o3, $o4, $o5, $o6, $o7, $o8);` after getting few variables as Getopt and few as hardcoded work too? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnkP  I'm glad that you are working more with this and asking :).  This is a matter of your design, how to take user input.  There are indeed various ways.  I think I've used something slightly different in my answer to your next question, with states being modules.  The `%h` way of `GetOptions` is a little tricky, in what options you can explicitly state and how to do that. In short, if you specifically name options (`o1` etc) in `GetOptions()` then you _have to_ declare variables for them separately, as well. So you have them in the hash _and_ as variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @zdim! Yes I am taking this a learning opportunity by modifying the code! :) So once I define some variables separately and some in Getopt, instead of using `my($o1, $o2) = qw(o1 o2)` and getting `%input` in `Getopt` I can use `Getoptions(  'o1=s');     o2 = 'abc.txt' ;                my %input = ( 'o1' => \$o1,  $o2 );`?

Comment: @AnkP  Two things: (1) You can have `%` for `GetOptions`, and then any input becomes a key-value pair in it.  Then you use it as `$h{'o1'}` etc. You can also specifically list variables into which some options go, typically ones used often; then you need to declare those variables.  Then you can use them more simply as `$opt1` etc.  Read the docs for it very carefully -- and you'll just have to play with it, it is a little tricky.  Try what you are asking, I am not sure. If you end up being stuck with it that may well be a reasonable question in its own right (after you've tried it a bit).

Comment: @AnkP  The second thing: (2) You can have the hash, _and_ other completely unrelated options (then the hash _must come first_, see docs). This is what I used in your other (next) question.  Back to point (1), how you use the hash _and_ its specific parts (stated separately as variables) is really a little tricky.  Just try, tweak it around until you get it as you like it.  I used that here (and in the other question) because you need to relate input to field names, so those options serve _two_ masters. So it was very convenient to state them separately.

Comment: @AnkP  Back to your question: yes, you can hard-code some of these, and add those variables to the hash later.  That hash is a variable in your code, once processed by `GetOpt` (at start). You can add to it if you wish.  (Try it.)  You can also list all input as separate variables, I used the hash-input only because I considered it convenient here.  If the number of input grows, new things get added, etc -- you don't have to track individual variables; the new input gets absorbed by the hash. You can loop through keys to process and code may not even need to change as new options are added.

Comment: Thanks zdim! yes I will try tweaking this. I understand the concept now, one more question, the command `my ($o1, $o2) = qw(o1 o2);` is similar to `GetOptions( \%input, 'o1=s' => $o1,` right? As I was not sure about ways to use 'qw'. thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnkP  (1) `qw(one two)` is exactly the same as `('one', 'two')`. It just `q`uotes `w`ords.  (2) You can do: (a) either, `my $opt1 = 'o1'; my %h; GetOptions(\%h, "$opt1=s");`, in which case input `-o1 value` gets assigned to `$opt1`, _while also being in the `%h`_. (b) Or, have `my $var; my %h; GetOptions(%h, 'var=i' => \$var)`, where input `--val 23` is assigned to `$var`, which has nothing to do with the `%h`, it's a separate input and variable.  I used both in my answer to your other question, see that.

Comment: @AnkP  Once you've processed this let's clean up :).  Drop me a line when you get to do that so that I do it, too.

Comment: I will start the cleanup soon and may be combine and modify all these queries into one query so that they are relevant to your answers in the end! thanks!