# Use user input to populate a template config file having different subsections while maintaining the order

Tags: perl

I am trying to read in a template config file (template.config) that looks like this (the number of required input options can increase):

```
[module1]

;;path to speedseq package binary directory
$;SPEEDSEQ_BIN_DIR$; = /usr/local/packages/
;;Sequence file 1
$;Seq1File$; =
;;Sequence file 2
$;Seq2File$; =
;;Read Group
$;Read_Group$;='@RG\tID:NA12878\tSM:NA12878\tPL:ILLUMINA\tLB:NA12878\tPU:NA12878'
;;Reference
$;Reference$; =

[module2]

;;Output Chromosome
$;Chromosome$; = 
;;use --v for verbose summary
$;OTHER_ARGS$; = --v
```

whose fields will get populated by user input on the command line, e.g.:

```
perl script.pl template.config USER_INPUT.txt USER_INPT2.txt USER_INPUT_REF.txt USER_INPUT_CHR.txt
```

and it will output a new populated config file like this:

```
[module1]

;;path to speedseq package binary directory
$;SPEEDSEQ_BIN_DIR$; = /usr/local/packages/
;;Sequence file 1
$;Seq1File$; = "USER_INPUT.txt"
;;Sequence file 2
$;Seq2File$; = "USER_INPT2.txt"
;;Read Group
$;Read_Group$;='@RG\tID:NA12878\tSM:NA12878\tPL:ILLUMINA\tLB:NA12878\tPU:NA12878'
;;Reference
$;Reference$; = "USER_INPUT_REF.txt"

[module2]

;;Output Chromosome
$;Chromosome$; = "USER_INPUT_CHR.txt"
;;use --v for verbose summary
$;OTHER_ARGS$; = --v
```

The lines within each module should remain same and but order of modules can vary eg Module2 can come before Module1. How can I do this?

When I am trying to print out the hash keys to a file, the order is not same as the order in the input file. I even tried sort keys option but does not work. Can anyone please suggest? I am trying to make a hash of/in hash

1. To store the headers in `[format]`
2. To store the lines under each header

What I am using so far is -
I wrote a script to create two hashes but I am not able to get the desired order, can someone please point out what I am missing?

```
open($template.config, "<$sConfigFile") or die "Error! Cannot open $sConfigFile for reading: $!";

        while (<$template.config>) {
                $_ =~ s/\s+$//;
                next if ($_ =~ /^#/);
                next if ($_ =~ /^$/);

                if ($_ =~ m/^\[(\S+)\]$/) {
                $sComponent = $1;
                    next;
                }
                elsif ($_ =~ m/^;;\s*(.*)/) {
                    $sDesc .= "$1.";
                    next;
                }
                elsif ($_ =~ m/\$;(\S+)\$;\s*=\s*(.*)/) {
                    $sParam = $1;
                    $sValue = $2;

                    }

                    $sParam = $sValue = $sDesc = "";
                    next;
                }
            }
```

**Which does not consider the `[module1] , [mpdule2]` as subsections or headers and prints out all the filled keys in random order**

Comment: You haven't posted any code, and my mind-reading skills are rusty. Can you [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @MattJacob  It is not a duplicate.  It is similar, but this is a follow-up that altogether forms a sufficiently different problem.  There are critical differences in this question's requirements.  The post you link to can be understood as a module/sub-problem for this one.  However, in this form an altogether different approach may be needed. I think that it's a completely fair new question.

Comment: @zdim This question is: how can I use command line arguments to render a template? The other question is: how can I use command line arguments to render a template?

Comment: @MattJacob  Please read these questions carefully is you haven't, if you wish to call it a duplicate.  How you reduce the questions is incorrect. They ask how to process template files which are sufficiently different: one has a list of 'random' line-pairs, the other has multiple sections, with headers, with line-pairs in order that must be kept.  If you change text on the lines in two cases there will be only one similarity remaining (that lines are paired).  There may well be answers on SO that fit this, but unrelated to the other question you link to.

Comment: @MattJacob I think I understand now what you mean -- it is not about the command-line arguments, really;  it is about the template-file format, and that is different enough in the two cases.

Comment: I think my post has gone too complicated! My issue was just that I was not able to get the output in same order as the input template file. The input file in other post did have subsections, so order did not matter. I am working on reading the file into two hashes (which I guess might be little complicated for a perl newbie like me). I will update if my troubleshooting works. Thanks!

Comment: I think that your post is fine.  It clearly spells out what you want to do, clearly shows formats you work with, and (now) discusses with code what you tried or are trying.  In my opinion it is a good question.

Comment: I thjink we are missing a lot of information here. You don't explain what effect your `[module]` headers should have, or what variation of inputs and templates you need to cope with. In particular the last line `$;OTHER_ARGS$; = --v` of your sample template is particularly cryptic.

Comment: @Borodin  I very strongly disagree with marking it a duplicate. An "exact" duplicate? The requirements here make it a far more complicated problem: there are now sections in the file and order matters. I assure you that the answer to the "duplicate" does not answer this question;  I answered that one. Did you review it? If "yes", I will not comment on this again. (I am commenting so much here because I suggested to AnkP to make a new question as the requirements on the previous one evolved too far.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get some way towards what you need by storing a list of your hash keys in the order that you add them to the hash

Here's an example

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14.1;
use autodie;

my ($template_name, $seq_file, $seq2_file, $reference) = @ARGV;

my (%fields, @keys);

{
    open my $fh, '<', $template_name;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;
        next if /^\s*#/;

        s/^\s+//; s/\s+\z//;

        if ( /^;;/ ) {
            push @keys, $_;
        }
        elsif ( /^\$;/ ) {
            $fields{$keys[-1]} = $_;
        }
    }
}

print "$_ => $fields{$_}\n" for @keys;
```

However I'm not clear what you will gain by writing what is essentially your own custom template format

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the [module1]...[module2] tags in the template will be used by another program to parse/read the values provided under corresponding module (after its is populated with user input). Eg the information/lines under [module1] will be used by one program, [module2] information'lines will be used by a different program. So the order of Modules+their sections matters for this script